# How to put double ampersand in dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker

I wrote a dockerfile as below.

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12.18.3
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json
RUN yarn install
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

This works well. But I want to run yarn start with ampersand.
For example, I can run yarn start after .sh.

```
bash some.sh && yarn start
```

Therefore, if an error is occured in 'some.sh', 'yarn start' doesn't be executed. 
How can I put this option in dockerfile? Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if an error is occurred in 'some.sh', 'yarn start' doesn't be executed.

You have to option

- Ignore if an error occurred in `some.sh`
- **Do not run** `yarn start` if an error occurred in `some.sh`

For the first option

```
CMD ["sh", "-c","./some.sh ; yarn start"]
```

this will ignore even if `some.sh` exit with status code `1`.

The second option, do not run `yarn start` **if some.sh exit with `1`**, run otherwise.

```
CMD ["sh", "-c","./some.sh && yarn start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to call one `some.sh` script  (assuming your `COPY` it in your Dockerfile) which would:

- perform your commands
- call `yarn start` only if those commands have succeeded

That way, you manage the complexity of the start inside your shell script, rather than in a Dockerfile `CMD` (which calls only your script)